# Does my formula for 2020 AMC 10b Problem 25 already exists?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was doing some AMC practice when I solved this question: https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2020_AMC_10B_Problems/Problem_25, but I made my own formula for it in solution 8, which is that $D(a\times b^c)= 2^{c-1} \times (c+2)$ (D is function in question) I'm not sure if it works or if it already exists. Has anyone seen a formula like mine before or did I make one?

Comment: ...You didn't show us your formula.

Comment: Oops I forgot to actually state it, lemme change it a bit

Comment: "Wouldn't it be nice if this pattern held?" is a good way to guess an answer but that's all it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think we can consider this problem as a combination problem.

Solving the $D(b^c)$ is equivalent to such a problem, if we have $c$ identical balls, how many result we can get if we use some bar to divide those $c$ identical balls, for examples of $c=3$,

$$
●●● \\
●\mid●●\\
●●\mid●\\
●\mid●\mid●
$$

Note the showed second line and third line are different results, so here we have

$$
\binom{c-1}{0}+\cdots+\binom{c-1}{c-1}=(1+1)^{c-1}=2^{c-1}
$$

$~\binom{c-1}{k}$ means we have $c-1$ posible postions and can choose $k$ to insert bars.

Since we have $c$ balls, we need to choose serval positions from all $c-1$ positions to insert $c-1$ bars. So $D(b^c)=2^{c-1}(c\ge 1)$.

However for $D(a\times b^c)$, assume we have $c+1$ identical balls, the answer is $2^{c}$, but now color or shape of one ball is changed. Then we consider such a situation
$$
●\mid●●●\mid●\cdots ●●●\mid●●●
$$
Above shows one of situation that we insert k bars into $c+1$, now the ball $a$ is in these of $c+1$ balls, in fact, ball $a$ have $k+1$ posible positions, because we have $k$ bars now. So if we insert $k$ bars, the contribution to the answer is $\binom{k}{c}(k+1)$, so
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{c}(i+1)\binom{c}{i}=\sum_{i=0}^{c}i\binom{c}{i}+2^{c}=\sum_{i=1}^{c}i\binom{c}{i}+2^{c}
$$
$$
(1+x)^c=\sum_{i=0}^c \binom{c}{i}x^i \\
c(1+x)^{c-1}=\sum_{i=1}^c\binom{c}{i}ix^{i-1}
$$

Let $x=1$, we have

$$
c2^{c-1}=\sum_{i=1}^c\binom{c}{i}i
$$

Therefore

$$
\sum_{i=0}^{c}(i+1)\binom{c}{i}
=\sum_{i=1}^{c}i\binom{c}{i}+2^{c}=2^{c-1}(c+2)
$$

That is $D(a\times b^c)=2^{c-1}(c+2)$